# UseInMemoryDatabase with UseInternalServiceProvider. No database provider configured

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm having trouble injecting a custom `IAsyncQueryProvider` when using EntityFrameworkCore. To be more precise.. I am having trouble injecting the provider when using the in memory database functionality provided. Using a default provider (SqlServer), all works fine.

Here's my global `Startup.cs`

```
private void ConfigureEntityFrameworkWithSecurity(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddEntityFramework()
        .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
        .AddScoped<IAsyncQueryProvider, CustomEntityProvider>()
        .AddDbContext<APIContext>((sp, options) =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
                .UseInternalServiceProvider(sp);
        });
}
```

This works *flawlessly*, and I can put a breakpoint within `CustomEntityProvider` to verify that it is indeed being injected. At the moment, `CustomEntityProvider` simply implements `IAsyncQueryProvider`, and simply passes through the request. There is no logic contained within it.

When I'm running a test, I configure the webhost to use a different `Startup` file:

```
public class TestStartup : Startup
{
    public TestStartup(IHostingEnvironment env) : base(env)
    {
    }

    public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddDbContext<APIContext>((sp, options) =>
            {
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase()
                    .UseInternalServiceProvider(sp);
            });
        base.ConfigureServices(services);
    }
}
```

Running a test with `TestStartup` yields the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

And `APIContext` is correctly defined:

```
public class APIContext : DbContext
{
    public APIContext(DbContextOptions<APIContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    ...
}
```

Removing `UseInternalServiceProvider` from `TestStartup` works correctly - however, I don't want my tests to hit an actual database. Further, I would expect `UseInMemoryDatabase` to automatically inject dependencies into the service provider - as it works perfectly fine by itself.

The error is confusing because the in memory database *is* the provider I want to use.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, the solution is hair-tearingly simple. However, there seems to be very little documentation about using dependency injection with the in-memory database functionality. It appears to be one or the other. Hopefully this question will provide help for future people misfortunate enough to run into this.

I downloaded the EntityFramework source to investigate, and found that calling `UseInMemoryDatabase` creates an extension `InMemoryOptionsExtension` which itself will add to the service provider, namely:

```
public virtual void ApplyServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    Check.NotNull(services, nameof(services));

    services.AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase();
}
```

And the solution is as simple as it looks:

```
public class TestStartup : Startup
{
    public TestStartup(IHostingEnvironment env) : base(env)
    {
    }

    public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
            .AddDbContext<APIContext>((sp, options) =>
            {
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase().UseInternalServiceProvider(sp);
            });
        base.ConfigureServices(services);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the exact error I am encountering. However I'm using EntityFramework.InMemory v2.0.0 and `UseInMemoryDatabase()` has become obsolete. You're right the documentation is limited and I'm guessing `services.AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase().AddDbContext<` is the new way to do it. Although every which way I  have this I still get the error. Any chance you've upgraded the Nuget package in the last year? Thanks.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I didn't end up taking my project very far; it was more of an experiment with .netcore than anything else. I'm not sure if `.AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase` is the *new* way to do it. As far as I remember, `options.UseInMemoryDatabase()` configures the context to use the in-memory provider, while `.AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()` configures the dependency injection - so both need to be specified. I'll take a look when I'm home, after upgrading to latest.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43098065) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991088) may be related to the problem you're having

Comment: @JeremyThompson Unfortunately, I've been unable to get the solution into working condition to try it out on version 2.0.0. Did the above links help at all?

Comment: Thanks for your help Rob, this answer shows the correct way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38897560/495455 - owe you a beer @ The Nixon Bar most lunch times.

Comment: @JeremyThompson Hmm, I'm curious how that works but the above doesn't - they both appear to be adding to the configuration builder. Anyway, glad you got it sorted in the end!

Answer (score -6):

Click on -> properties Folder inside your solution Explorer.
Open -> launchSettings.json file api/TodoItems

"profiles": {
"IIS Express": {
"commandName": "IISExpress",
"launchBrowser": true,
*****"launchUrl": "swagger",*****
"environmentVariables": {
"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
}
},

"profiles": {
"IIS Express": {
"commandName": "IISExpress",
"launchBrowser": true,
****"launchUrl": "api/TodoItems",****
"environmentVariables": {
"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
}
},