# Entity Framework Core: DbContextOptionsBuilder does not contain a definition for 'usesqlserver' and no extension method 'usesqlserver'

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am new to EF core and I'm trying to get it to work with my ASP.NET Core project.

I get the above error in my `startup.cs` when trying configure the `DbContext` to use a connection string from config. I am following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro).

The problematic code is in `startup.cs`:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using tracV2.models;
using tracV2.data;

namespace tracV2
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);

            string conn = Configuration.GetConnectionString("optimumDB");

            services.AddDbContext<tracContext>(options => options.usesqlserver(conn));
        }
```

The `UseSqlServer` method is recognized if I put it directly into the context:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace tracV2.data
{
    public class tracContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("myrealconnectionstring");
        }
```

All my research online points to missing references, but I can't seem to find out which one I am missing ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cbxl.png)).

Comment: Same thing, intellissense does not find the method either.

Comment: This is a known issue in the project system. See [dotnet/project-system#1741](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/1741)

Answer (score 812):

First we install the [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/) NuGet Package:

```
PM > Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Then, after importing the namespace with

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

we add the database context:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<AspDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("optimumDB")));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already did that. I'm starting to suspect something is corrupted in my original project. I will try to see if I can reproduce from a new project ...

Comment: This answer should be marked as correct answer not the other ones, reason is that the method UseSqlServer is from this package and not the other packages.

Comment: This isn't working for me. I have nuget packages: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools and "using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;" at the top but still get the error

Comment: You also need this constructor `public AspDbContext(DbContextOptions<AspDbContext> options) : base(options) {  }`

Comment: For future users who face this issue, the version of the nuget package matters. It wasn't able to resolve for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 6.0.1 for me when .NET core version was 5.0.0. I had to install a lower version of the nuget package for it to resolve the  red line error.

Comment: In my case I although I have installed packages
 
```Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design```

.dotnet ef tool was not installed  

```dotnet tool install dotnet-ef``` 

after installing and uninstall and reinstall Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer fix that issue

Answer (score 142):

adding 
`using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

manually solved the problem for me

[Found that here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7891)

**Edit...**

for dotnet core 3.1 add

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`

Comment: This is the answer.

Comment: Fixed it for me! Somehow it wasn't in the suggestions list ctrl+.

Comment: Fixed it for me in 2019 with .Net Core 2.2

Comment: Yes, but I found that the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer package was needed for dotnetcore 3.1.  Prior to that, it appeared that Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore alone was enough.

Answer (score 44):

Follow the steps below.

Install Entity Framework Core Design and SQL Server database provider for Entity Framework Core:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Import Entity Framework Core:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

And configure your DbContext:

```cs
var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("myDb");
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString)
);
```

Comment: This part of the solution where you are manually adding the `using` statement is what worked for me - seems my editor didnt detect the package in the assembly

Comment: Worked for me and you do need to manually add the using statement as the IDE doesn't provide a hint.

Answer (score 39):

Install below NuGet Package will solve your issue

**Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer**

> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Comment: Add a little bit more explanation about how this one line command will solve the op's problem. Specifically, here you are addressing a package so you need to explain how that package works.

Comment: **"DbContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer"** is available in _Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer_ package,  So need to add the reference of it to solve the build issue.

Answer (score 24):

> [EntityFramework UseSqlServer Solved](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Comment: installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer solved it for me

Answer (score 11):

I believe this can be solved by adding a project reference to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design
```

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer wasn't directly installed in my project, but the .Design package will install it anyway as a prerequisite.

Comment: Installing unnecessary package which brings in required project as transitive dependency is not a solution to the issue.

Comment: You assume the package is unnecessary, yet it fixed my project when I had the exact same issue.

Comment: That package is unnecessary for the current question. It may be required for different issue but not this one.

Comment: As of today, July 27th, you can install just Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer package and it will solve the issue

Comment: As of today, 5/Feb/2018, you still need to add the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design package. This was observed using an ASP.NET Core 2.0.1 web project.

Comment: Solved my issue by this solution, Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

The Package is missing. Open Package Manager Console and execute the code below:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Answer (score 10):

your solution works great.

When I saw this video till 17 Minute:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fom80TujpYQ
I was facing a problem here:

```
 services.AddDbContext<PaymentDetailContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")));
```

**UseSqlServer not recognizes so I did this**
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Version 3.1.5

&
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

Then my problem is solved. About me: basically I am a purely PHP programmer since beginning and  today only I started .net coding, thanks for good community in .net

Answer (score 8):

Install the following packages from Nuget :-

1. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core

Answer (score 7):

I was using Visual Studio Code.

1) Try to install the package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' by specifying the version number.

***VS Code***:

'dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -v 1.1.1'

***Visual Studio:-***

'Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -v 1.1.1'

Refer the link '[Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45703733/package-microsoft-entityframework-sqlserver-is-incompatilbe-with-all-framewo/45703734#45703734)' for doing it.

2) Then add the namespace '**using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;**' manually  in the Startup.cs file.

Refer the below link
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7891.

3) If you get any dependency issue for '*Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design'*, like "Package '**Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project**" ,we need to run the below command,

***VS Code:-***

dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design -v 1.1

***Visual Studio***

Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design -v 1.1

Answer (score 7):

Project -> ManageNugetPackages -> Browse -> Search "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" and install or update.

Answer (score 5):

In my case :-
I have hit the below command and it is resolved.
**Command**

> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -v 1.1.1

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by top scoring answer by Win you may need to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer NuGet Package, but please note that this question is using asp.net core mvc.  In the latest ASP.NET Core 2.1, MS have included what is called a metapackage called Microsoft.AspNetCore.App

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-2.2

You can see the reference to it if you right-click the ASP.NET Core MVC project in the solution explorer and select `Edit Project File`

You should see this metapackage if ASP.NET core webapps the using statement

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />`

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer is included in this metapackage. So in your Startup.cs you may only need to add:

`using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio, check the ***NuGet Package Manager => Manage Packages for Solution***, check all this packages, whether got **installed** in your solution or not, as below:

1. **EntityFrameworkCore**
2. **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore**
3. **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory**
4. **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational**
5. **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core**
6. **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer**
7. **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools**

I solved the same issues after check all the above packages have been installed.

Answer (score 4):

**Install package, EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:**

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Version 3.1.3
```

Nuget:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/

Comment: Get the current version from
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same problem. I added the following. It works for me

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Answer (score 4):

I add `SqlServer` and `Sqlite` to my project, the same problem arises.

For me, I installed `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` earlier, it's version is `5.0.6`. Now `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` version is `5.0.7`. There is no `UserSqlServer` method after installation.

#### 1. Try to upgrade the tool version to be consistent

Try to modify the version in csproj:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.7">
```

Or open `NuGet` to update the package.

#### 2. Restart your Visual Studio

If it won't help you, **the most important thing is to restart VS**

And then, everything is OK.

**reference**
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/7891

Answer (score 3):

first add `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`

next add in your .cs file `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

finally add this in your core `Startup.cs`

```cs
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MovieContext")));
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

For me this issue happened with Visual Studio Code and I was able to fix with 2 steps:

1. Manually adding `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`
2. Running `dotnet build` in terminal.

Answer (score 3):

> > Easy way to fix this issue

Error message:
[image]

Solution:
to install "microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver" with NuGet
[image]

Fixed :
[image]

PS: make sure you have using EF on the content "using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;" 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still having this problem:
Use NuGet to install:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies

This problem is related to the use of Castle Proxy with EFCore.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. It is also mentioned at learn.microsoft.com _"The simplest way to use lazy-loading is by installing the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies package and enabling it with a call to UseLazyLoadingProxies."_ [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy)

Answer (score 2):

> **If you are facing this issue in case of Sqlite then**

.
I think this is the problem with version of Sqlite,I had the same problem when I was using this versions of [SqLite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/netcore/new-db-sqlite)

**Version 2.2.4**:

[image]

After checking version [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/master/samples/core/GetStarted/AspNetCore/EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb.Sqlite/EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb.csproj) [image] I changed the version then it worked.

[image]

No error after using this

**Version 2.1.2**:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Wow so many answers yet none mentioned this [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/) package!

Add the reference to this package: 
`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="2.2.2" />` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Install-Package:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

then add the top of your class:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Then add Datacontext

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<LibraryDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Answer (score 2):

I read and did everything instructed in every answer and I just found out my problem was a missing constructor on my DbContext

```
public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options) : base(options) { }
```

I hope this helps anyone facing the same problem I was.

Answer (score 1):

I got around this by simply:

Add `SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions` to the class in question
Resolve `SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions`

This fixes the issue, must be missing some reference by default.

Answer (score 1):

I had this trouble when I moved to *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer* v3.0.0 and *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools* v3.0.0

When I changed back to v2.2.6 on both libraries, the error went away. This is more of a workaround than a solution but it'll get you up and running till the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Currently working with Entity Framework Core 3.1.3. None of the above solutions fixed my issue.

However, installing the package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies on my project fixed the issue. Now I can access the UseLazyLoadingProxies() method call when setting my DBContext options.

Hope this helps someone. See the following article:

[Lazy Loading in EF Core](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/lazy-loading)

Answer (score 0):

Copying the following code into the TodoApi.csproj from https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/tutorials/first-web-api/sample/TodoApi solved similar issue for me.

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Microsoft.AspNetCore.All may be excessive but it includes EntityFrameworkCore

Answer (score 0):

For asp.net core version 2.1 make sure to add the following package to fix the problem. (At least this fix the issue using SQLite)

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
```

Here is the reference of the documentation using SQLite with entity framework core.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/netcore/new-db-sqlite

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the line

```cs
 services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlite().AddDbContext<MovieContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MovieContext")));
```

in the ConfigureServices method in the Startup.cs

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue but problem went off after going back and fixing `DbContext` incorrect syntax issue such as it should have been `ExampleDbContextClass: DbContext` whereas I had missed `DbContext` part in Context Class where you define your `DbSet`. Also, I verified following dependencies are needed in order to achieve connection to SqlServer.
`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.0" /> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.6" />`
Also verify that Version you install is less than your project's current version to be on safe side. Such as if your project is using 3.1 do not try to use newer one which would be for example 3.1.9. I had issue with that too.

Answer (score 0):

Project is works in DotNET Core 3.1+ or higher(future)

Add this package:

1. NuGet:    `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`
2. Project Config (.csproj): `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.8">`

Comment: This is not correct. `UseSqlServer` is part of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer as said in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

In my Case in .Net6, After I installed (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer,
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools) I had to
**Install "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" To Get the definition Of UseSqlServer() function.**

Comment: this does not appear to work - at least anymore. Looks like the correct nuget package is Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.   I tried the above nuget package - it still did not have the 'usesqlserver' option. Then i added this package and it worked fine

Answer (score -1):

I installed these three of them in the package manager console and it worked.

`Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design -Version 3.1.4 Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 3.1.8 Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Version 3.1.8`