# Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in the project

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I was trying to add the package named `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` by running the command.

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

in Visual Studio Code, but I get this error:

> Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0" (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project 'C:\users\username..'

Answer (score 12):

I was using version 1.1. Try to run the below command including the version number:

**Visual Studio Code:**

'dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -v 1.1.1'

**Visual Studio:-**

'Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -v 1.1.1'

Answer (score 5):

In order to use version `2.0.0` of EF Core, you need the [.NET Core 2.0 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core) and/or [Visual Studio 2017 version 15.3](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes).

Comment: Link for Core 2.0            https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.0.0-download.md

Answer (score 2):

This Might Be Happening due to generated NuGet Cache While Installing Packages.
Go to Tools>Options>NuGet Package Manager>General and "Clear All NuGet Cache".
This Worked in my case(VS Community 2019).

Also try to update Source of nuget.org by going to Tools>Options>NuGet Package Manager>Package Source and click Update Source in case of VS 2017.

Answer (score 0):

In case I had a similar issue with the same error message.

I cloned a project which was using netcoreapp2.1 and my version was 2.2.

I updated the TargetFramework (*.csproj) to netcoreapp2.2. Then, I was able to install the package.

Answer (score 0):

Install the SDK required (eg: dotnet-sdk-5.0.203-win-x64.exe).delete obj and bin folders.
Rebuild the project. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it this way.

.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0

---

Then I installed the net6.0 version and it worked.