# How to configure EF connection string from .NET Standard library? No UseSqlServer in DbContextOptionsBuilder?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-standard

I am getting below error while trying to access the entities in side datacontext.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.'
```

My code is in .Net standard library and not all the methods to configure options are available(which most of the answers suggest).

Below is my code. I am trying to test it in console application.

TestCode:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
        {
            var stdQuery = (from d in context.My_Employees
                            select new { Company = d.COMPANY_NAME, Emp = d.EMP_NAME });
            foreach (var q in stdQuery)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Company Name : " + q.Company + ", Emp Name : " + q.Emp);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

DataContext code is below(.Net standard library)

```
     public partial class MyEntities : DbContext
    { 
     public virtual DbSet<My_Employee> My_Employees { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<My_Company> My_Companies { get; set; }

 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
        {
            if (!builder.IsConfigured)
            {
                string conn ="<ConnectionString>"; 
                //builder.  <There is no option to mention UseSqlServer>
            }
            base.OnConfiguring(builder);
        }
}
```

Any idea how to resolve this? I am really stuck there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43098065/2864740 - found via refined 'issue' query of "UseSqlServer .net standard".

Comment: Thanks @user2864740. It helped me to resolve the issue.