# What is the recommended way to seed an in-memory Sqlite database?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, cypress

I am trying to implement an in-memory Sqlite database on my C# application to use for testing purposes. I would like to seed the database during startup so that I can control the data used in my Cypress end to end tests. From my research online, I see 2 ways to do this.

The first is to add data to the context using the `DbContext.AddRange()` method, as shown in Mircosoft's example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-without-the-database#sqlite-in-memory).

The second is within the OnModelCreating() method, where you can add data to a model like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().HasData(
    new Book { BookId = 1, AuthorId = 1, Title = "Hamlet" },
    new Book { BookId = 2, AuthorId = 1, Title = "King Lear" },
    new Book { BookId = 3, AuthorId = 1, Title = "Othello" }
);
```

Documentation on Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding

In either case, I believe you also have to use `context.Database.EnsureCreated();`, but I am not sure where to put it.

What is the reccommended way to seed my database with test data?

Comment: I ended up writing a small separate application to create, update and seed the database, including a special seed dedicated for testing. But you would typically not add a database just for testing. What is the actual use case? Are you sure plain files are not more suitable?

Comment: I am writing end to end tests using Cypress and I need my database set up for the tests so that they can run predictably.

Comment: Sqlite is the production db?

Comment: No, for prod we use sql server, but we want to use an in memory db for testing.

Comment: How is start the API? Can you pass argument to the program?

Comment: That is not my issue, I can check if I am in test or prod. I need help setting up my sqlite db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with a SQL Server DB image that I spin up on a Docker container each time I run the tests, because there were differences between SQLite and Sql Server that couldn't be surmounted and they were interfering with the tests.
But if someone would want to populate a Sqlite database for testing, you can add  something like this to the `Configure()` method in `Startup`:

```
context.Database.EnsureCreated();
//call service to populate database
SqliteDbSeeder.PopulateDatabase(context);
```

The `SqliteDbSeeder.PopulateDatabase()` method uses `context.AddRange()` and `SaveChanges()` to add entities to the database. I actually saved them in json files, converted them to entities and then added them to the database.

Answer (score 5):

In-memory would seem to be a limiting factor from the perspective of the test, since Cypress can't directly interop with a database created by EF purely in it's memory space.

But you can create a file-based Sqlite db via [node-sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3), which you can seed by calling a Cypress task.

There is a sample recipe here [server-communication__seeding-database-in-node](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/server-communication__seeding-database-in-node)

This has a `cy.task('seed:db')` set up in `cypress.config.js`

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

const { seed } = require('./server/db')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:7082',
    supportFile: false,
    setupNodeEvents (on, config) {
      on('task', {
        'seed:db' (data) {
          return seed(data).then(() => {
            return data
          })
        },
      })
    },
  },
})
```

In the Cypress recipe, `./server/db.js` would need some code from the node-sqlite3 package instead of what it currently has (using json files as the db), for example

```js
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');

db.serialize(() => {
    db.run("CREATE TABLE lorem (info TEXT)");

    const stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?)");
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        stmt.run("Ipsum " + i);
    }
    stmt.finalize();

    db.each("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM lorem", (err, row) => {
        console.log(row.id + ": " + row.info);
    });
});

db.close();
```

Your tests would probably want another task to create/update/delete database records at certain points in the test flow. You should be able to adapt the above code to handle that.

Comment: Thanks, I am not looking to test the db from Cypress. I am looking to write end to end tests that can act like a user and do non flaky tests, for example update a form, approve a form etc. I would need data in my db to represent a form that is waiting for approval.

Comment: Why do you think this is just to test the db? `seed:db` means just that - set up initial conditions for the test.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to implement an in-memory Sqlite database on my C# application to use for testing purposes.

Since the goal is to use the app for unit-testing then to use `HasData` approach you will need to create a class which will inherit from the application context (or you will have the seeded data in actual context).

Also the `HasData` is more limited approach due to the data being applied to all instances of context for tests. It can make sense to but there some shared data which is used for all cases but I personally tend to introduce such data just via some shared method (which will do the `AddRange` and `SaveChanges`) which is called in some kind of [one time setup](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/onetimesetup.html) (depending on test framework used) which is more flexible approach and allows more fine-graned control of needed.

Also one more thing I would suggest to look into - using [testcontainers](https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/) for such tests instead of in-memory SQLite, i.e. spin up database container set it up as needed and use it, which will result in more relevant test results by using specific database server.

Comment: I updated my question to clarify: I am writing end to end tests using the Cypress framework so I need the data to be setup from the back end and my tests will not be dealing with the database setup at all.

Comment: @SoraTeichman then more info would be needed about deployment, but personally I still would go with the second approach for the same reasons - for test setup check if environment is a test one, call `EnsureCreated` and fill and save data on startup ([as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71461296/how-do-you-do-database-ensurecreated-in-aspnet-core-web-application-using-net/71461320#71461320))