# Entity Framework Core InMemory database tests break when run in parallel

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, testing, entity-framework-core

When running all the test, I'm eventually getting errors saying:

> "An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 125"

This doesn't happen when each test is run separately.

The funny thing is that each test works with a different DbName, to avoid any conflict:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test1() 
{
    using (var context = CreateTestingContext()) 
    {
        ...
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void Test2() 
{
    using (var context = CreateTestingContext()) 
    {
        ...
    }
}

protected static SGDTPContext CreateTestingContext([CallerMemberName] string dbName = "TestingDb")
{
    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase(dbName);
    return new MyDbContext(builder.Options);
}
```

It's really strange, because when I run the tests individually, they are Green! and when I run them all at the same time, some eventually fail.

NOTE: I'm using the integrated MSTest from Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: VS will run the tests in multiple threads, and it appears that your test methods run on the same database. also note that tests from multiple files will not necessarily run sequentially, i.e. the Class initializer of some classes may be run before the Class Cleanup methods of preceding test classes.

Comment: How can they run on the same database if I'm explicitly passing a different name to UseInMemoryDatabase?

Comment: You are passing the same name, according to your code. TestingDb.

Comment: @cassandrad the [CallerMemberName] attribute tells the compiler to inject the name of the caller method, so it's "Test1" and "Test2".

Comment: Okay, then, just to check that everything is working as expected, you can add simple logging to verify that the name is what you expect.

Comment: You could also try using a random guid as the database name, to completely rule out any DB name conflicts.

Comment: @SuperJMN Could you find a solution to your issue? I am also struggling with it for days... :S

Comment: @mirind4 Yes! It seems that I was in the end using nameof wrong. If you pass a different name to the dbName, it should work.

Comment: @SuperJMN Nice, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Inspired by your question, each test method I used guid to be the databaseName. Finally this problem was solve. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ran into the same issue, solution was to use different databaseName for each Test Class. When doing that you get the same dbcontext in the test class, but it will not collide with different threads when running all tests at once.

```
        protected readonly YourDbContext _inMemoryContext;
        protected readonly DbContextOptions<YourDbContext> _options;

        _options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<YourDbContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "WhateverNameforClassScope").Options;

       _inMemoryContext = new YourDbContext(_options);
```

Comment: Sure wish there was more, well, context around that code. e.g. does the `DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>().UseInMemory...` go in a/the Setup() method (for this class' unit tests of course)?

Comment: Well you can use it as a ClassFixture or if it's fine to create new instance for each test you can initialize those on test class constructor.