# Tests running simultaneously fail with "The instance of entity type ... cannot be tracked"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, in-memory-database

I'm running some unit tests on an asp.net core 2.0 project, using EF core and an in-memory database.

I'm creating the database like this:

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
        .BuildServiceProvider();
var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TDatabaseContext>();
builder.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
    .UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider)
    .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
var context = new MyDatabaseContext(builder.Options);
```

According to [this post (How to isolate EF InMemory database per XUnit test)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38890269/how-to-isolate-ef-inmemory-database-per-xunit-test), using a separate service provider and using a different name for every in-memory DB instance should ensure that each test has its own database which is not shared with other tests.

However, my tests run fine when I run them separately, but fail if I run them all together, with errors like this:

> *System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'SomeModelObject' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value 'Id:1' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.*

Is there anything else I should do to make sure that the DB context is not shared among different tests?

Comment: Can you show sample test?

Comment: I tried to create a simple project that reproduces the problem, but I'm failing... this behavior seems to be very erratic

Comment: A simple test showing how the setup is done and how the test works might help. I don't think the whole project is needed.

Comment: I don't want to post the whole project, but the problem is that with the simple test the problem is not there :/

Comment: So there must be something else wrong in test not the setup you have shown. The setup should work.

Comment: Do you have this setup at the beginning of each test? Or is this done in other way?

Comment: Problem with  - how you are using your context and where it is created. Seems like context instance shared between test methods. You can try to move context creation inside every method and check if problem still appear